# How to get the union of two sets of objects that inherit from a common class

Tags: c#, linq, union

Say I have two classes, Plane and Car, which both inherit from Vehicle

```
public class Vehicle
{
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
}

public class Plane : Vehicle
{
}
```

How do I take a list of planes and a list of cars and union them into a single list of vehicles? I tried the following, but there was an error on cars saying the best overload has to take a receiver of type IEnumerable

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = cars.Union(planes);
```

Is there an easier way of doing this than using two .Select loops to cast all the objects to Vehicle?

Comment: minor sidenote: since a car cannot be a plane, you can use `Concat` instead of `Union` (unless the list themselves should be 'distinct'ed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the enumeration to the common base type:

```
var vehicles = cars.Cast<Vehcile>().Union(planes);
```

The reason bieng that `Union`'s signature is the following:

```
Union<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
```

In your code, form `first` the compiler reasons out that `TSource` is `Car`, and therefore `second` has the wrong type; `IEnumerable<Plane>` instead of the expected `IEnumerable<Car>`.

Bear in mind that in type inference the compiler won't bactrack and try something else if inference goes wrong, that is, it wont do the following:

1. `first` is `IEnumerable<Car>`, so `TSource` *could be* `Car`.
2. `second` is not `IEnumerable<Car>`, so `TSource` can not be `Car`.
3. Is there a common type `TSource` so that both `IEnumerable<Car>` and `IEnumerable<Plane>` can be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<TSource>`? Yes, `Vehicle`, therefore `TSource` is `Vehicle`.